# How to match string that ignore upper or lower case when using Text.Regex.Posix in haskell?

Tags: regex, haskell

I know posix regex use ?i to ignore upper or lower case

but when I test it:

```
"a" =~ "?i:a" :: Bool
```

I got a error.

How to write it right?

Comment: AFAIK, `?i:a` is not a valid regular expression in POSIX. do you have any source ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `?i:` prefix to indicate a case-insensitive regular expression isn't part of the POSIX standard for regular expressions, and it isn't supported by `Text.Regex.Posix`.  Instead, you need to specify a flag when the regular expression is compiled.  This means you can't use the `=~` operator, because that operator always uses default compilation flags.

Instead, you'll probably want to define a helper function:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Data.Bits
import Text.Regex.Posix

-- | Compile a case-insensitive regular expression.
makeIRegex :: RegexMaker Regex CompOption ExecOption source => source -> Regex
makeIRegex = makeRegexOpts (defaultCompOpt .|. compIgnoreCase) defaultExecOpt
```

and then you can write:

```
> match (makeIRegex "a") "a" :: Bool
True
> match (makeIRegex "a") "A" :: Bool
True
>
```